# Missing Steps between these two equations

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I'm reading a paper at the moment which starts with the following:
$$q = -V(\bar{r})$$

In the following line, the authors move from this equation to the following
$$\frac{d}{dt}q = -\nabla V(\bar{r})\cdot\frac{d}{dt}\bar{r}$$

I feel like it may be some vector calculus identity...Any thoughts?

Comment: Looks like chain rule in cartesian coordinates system.

Comment: any chance of a quick note? I can't quite see it.

Comment: d/dt= d/dx * dx/dt + d/dy * dy/dt + d/dz * dz/t

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 3 dimensional cartesian coordinate system

\begin{equation}
\overline{r}(t)=(x(t),y(t),z(t))
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
-\frac{d}{dt}q=\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial V}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{\partial V}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dt}=
\Big(\frac{\partial V}{\partial x},\frac{\partial V}{\partial y},\frac{\partial V}{\partial z}\Big)\cdot\Big(\frac{dx}{dt},\frac{dy}{dt},\frac{dz}{dt} \Big)=
\nabla V(\bar{r})\cdot\frac{d}{dt}\bar{r}
\end{equation}